# Python: change something inside a string respecting length constrains

Tags: python, string, python-3.x, replace, formatting

I am looking for a smarter solution to do what my code does.
I have to explore a text file. There are many Materials inside this text, and I want to change some material properties by replacing these values with new ones.
This is the Material structure:

```
  Material,
    PLASTERBOARD-1,          !- Name
    MediumSmooth,            !- Roughness
    0.01200,                 !- Thickness {m}
    0.16000,                 !- Conductivity {W/m-K}
    950.000,                 !- Density {kg/m3}
    840.00,                  !- Specific Heat {J/kg-K}
    0.900000,                !- Thermal Absorptance
    0.600000,                !- Solar Absorptance
    0.600000;                !- Visible Absorptance
```

This is my actual code:

```
from tempfile import mkstemp
from shutil import move
from os import fdopen, remove

def update_capacity(idf_file_path, material, capacity):
    check = False
    #Create temp file
    fh, abs_path = mkstemp()
    with fdopen(fh,'w') as new_file:
        with open(idf_file_path) as old_file:
            for line in old_file:
                if material in line:
                    check = True
                if check:
                    if '!- Conductivity {W/m-K}' in line:
                        line = '    '+str(capacity)+ ','
                        i = 26 - len(str(capacity))
                        while(i>0):
                            line +=' '
                            i-=1
                        line += '!- Conductivity {W/m-K}\n'
                        line.strip('(')
                        check= False
                new_file.write(line)
            #Remove original file
            old_file.close()
            new_file.close()
            remove(idf_file_path)
        #Move new file
        move(abs_path, idf_file_path)
    return idf_file_path

mat = 'FIBERGLASS QUILT-1'
cap = 2,0
idf_file = 'D:\\users\\f35943c\\Downloads\\Exercise1A.idf'

update_capacity(idf_file, mat, cap)
```

From `if material in line` to `new_file.write(line)` is where I want to optimize my code. Furthermore, strip does not work as I wanted, because I can't remove the parenthesis inside the line.
This is my benchmark string `"    0.16000,                 !- Conductivity {W/m-K}"` and I have to respect the numbers of characters before the `!- Conductivity {W/m-K}`

Can someone bring me to a smarter solution?

Comment: If you want to have lines with a constant width, check out python string formating. https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html Its easy to achieve with, no need to add spaces by hand. For removing parenthesis inside a string, you could use the replace method.

Comment: Thank you @voiDnyx I'll check it right now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Temporary Solution**:

```
            if material in line:
                check = True
            if check:
                if '!- Conductivity {W/m-K}' in line:
                    line = '    '+ str(capacity).ljust(25) + '!- Conductivity {W/m-K}\n'
                    check= False
            new_file.write(line)
```

If someone has a better idea, it would be welcome!

I  also found this usefull link about formatting string Python 3.x : https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-use-string-formatters-in-python-3

Answer (score 0):

You can rewrite,

```
if material in line and '!- Conductivity {W/m-K}' in line:
    line = '    '+str(capacity)+ ','
    i = 26 - len(str(capacity))
    while(i>0):
        line +=' '
        i-=1
    line += '!- Conductivity {W/m-K}\n'
    line.strip('(') # Try line.replace('oldvalue', 'newvalue') here
    check= False

new_file.write(line)
```

Comment: I already tried this solution, it does not work. Thank you anyway. Furthermore, I can't check in the same line both conditions, because they belong to two different lines, one after the other one. @uday S

Comment: different lines ? your code doesn't tell that !! Its checking for both conditions in the same line, each time. Can you recheck.

Comment: I' am using a boolean as a flag to have memory about the past condition, in the past line. I use:if material in line: check = True.

Comment: Got you !! missed to notice you are resetting after processing the complete file.